# spring - get online users

Tags: spring, spring-security

i want get online users list

this is my code

**web.xml**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?expire" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

and service

```
@Service
public class UserSessionRegistry {

   @Autowired
   private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

   public List<User> getOnlineUsers() {
      List<User> retValue = new ArrayList<User>();
      List<Object> onlineUsers = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
      for (Object usr : onlineUsers) {
         retValue.add((User) usr);
      }
      return retValue;
   }
}
```

but always return null as results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring-security have changed as below and the result was correct

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
            session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?expire" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using this code you can get all online user except the user which try to get.

And Implement SessionRegistry bean first into your spring-security configuraton.

```html
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       String userName = auth.getName(); 
      
 List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

 List<UserInfo> usersInfoList = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

 for (Object principal: principals) {
     if (principal instanceof UserInfo) {
      if(!((UserInfo) principal).getUsername().equals(userName)){ 
      for(SessionInformation sess :sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false)){
       if(!sess.isExpired()){
        usersInfoList.add((UserInfo) sess.getPrincipal());
       }
      }
      
      }
     }
```

Comment: What is `UserInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

According to spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#list-authenticated-principals) you need to setup the [concurrency-control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions) and use `maximumSession` set to `-1` (if you don't need to control the number of concurrent sessions). This way you will register the `SessionRegistry` and have access to the principal information.